# Counting the number of times a user scrolled and moved his mouse using JS / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mouseevent

I'm trying to count the number of times a user scrolled the page (any direction) and moved his mouse using this jquery code:

```
    $(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
       scrolling++;
    });

    $(window).bind('mousemove',function(e){
       mouse_moved++;
    });
```

The problem with this is one scroll event or one mouse movement gives the variables 'scrolling' and 'mouse_moved' a very high amount instead of just incrementing it by one.

It seems whenever the scrubber / mouse position changed it is counting it as one event already, even though the original event isn't done yet.

How can I do this correctly? Count one scrolling and mouse movement event properly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to track your state, e.g. detect when scrolling/moving starts, then again when it ends. And you need to decide what "ending" means — how long does the mouse have to be stationary again before you decide it's stopped moving? 5ms? 10? 15?

```
var scrolling = 0;
var scrollTimeout = 0;
$(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
   cancelTimeout(scrollTimeout);
   scrollTimeout = setTimeout(doneScrolling, 10); // 10 = 10ms
});
function doneScrolling() {
    scrollTimeout = 0;
    ++scrolling;
}
```

...and similarly with the mouse move (with its own separate timer).